Having trouble with cloudflare pages website build failing
I am working on a website project and I am having trouble with re-deploying/building the website. I've been pushing my changes to github and hosting through Cloudflare, but the latest build keeps failing.
I have already tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.son and rerunning npm i --package-lock-only, npm install, and npm ci.
Full error:
baicd-deploy:
2024-10-07T10:00:44.297947Z Cloning repository...
2024-10-07T10:00:46.276814Z From https://github.com/NalaYiyuChen/baicd_deploy
2024-10-07T10:00:46.277439Z  * branch            912db9843a76a916663e4db908e99c1220c78443 -> FETCH_HEAD
2024-10-07T10:00:46.277564Z 
2024-10-07T10:00:46.346113Z HEAD is now at 912db98 website build at  home
2024-10-07T10:00:46.346896Z 
2024-10-07T10:00:46.43478Z  
2024-10-07T10:00:46.436135Z Using v2 root directory strategy
2024-10-07T10:00:46.475953Z Success: Finished cloning repository files
2024-10-07T10:00:48.132786Z Checking for configuration in a wrangler.toml configuration file (BETA)
2024-10-07T10:00:48.13343Z  
2024-10-07T10:00:48.258461Z No wrangler.toml file found. Continuing.
2024-10-07T10:00:48.422913Z Detected the following tools from environment: npm@9.6.7, nodejs@18.17.1
2024-10-07T10:00:48.423693Z Installing project dependencies: npm clean-install --progress=false
2024-10-07T10:00:51.212476Z npm ERR! code EUSAGE
2024-10-07T10:00:51.217559Z npm ERR! 
2024-10-07T10:00:51.21784Z  npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
2024-10-07T10:00:51.217951Z npm ERR! 
2024-10-07T10:00:51.21804Z  npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's @babel/core@7.9.0 does not satisfy @babel/core@7.25.7
2024-10-07T10:00:51.218125Z npm ERR! Missing: @ampproject/remapping@2.3.0 from lock file
2024-10-07T10:00:51.218224Z npm ERR! Missing: convert-source-map@2.0.0 from lock file
2024-10-07T10:00:51.218357Z npm ERR! Missing: @babel/core@7.9.0 from lock file
2024-10-07T10:00:51.218439Z npm ERR! Missing: @babel/core@7.9.0 from lock file
2024-10-07T10:00:51.218548Z npm ERR! Missing: typescript@5.6.2 from lock file
2024-10-07T10:00:51.21869Z  npm ERR! Missing: semver@5.7.2 from lock file
2024-10-07T10:00:51.218845Z npm ERR! 
2024-10-07T10:00:51.218953Z npm ERR! Clean install a project
2024-10-07T10:00:51.219047Z npm ERR! 
2024-10-07T10:00:51.219153Z npm ERR! Usage:
2024-10-07T10:00:51.219261Z npm ERR! npm ci
2024-10-07T10:00:51.22047Z  npm ERR! 
2024-10-07T10:00:51.220602Z npm ERR! Options:
2024-10-07T10:00:51.220699Z npm ERR! [--install-strategy <hoisted|nested|shallow|linked>] [--legacy-bundling]
2024-10-07T10:00:51.220902Z npm ERR! [--global-style] [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
2024-10-07T10:00:51.220979Z npm ERR! [--strict-peer-deps] [--no-package-lock] [--foreground-scripts]
2024-10-07T10:00:51.221144Z npm ERR! [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit] [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
2024-10-07T10:00:51.221272Z npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
2024-10-07T10:00:51.221396Z npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
2024-10-07T10:00:51.221541Z npm ERR! 
2024-10-07T10:00:51.221694Z npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
2024-10-07T10:00:51.221847Z npm ERR! 
2024-10-07T10:00:51.221976Z npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info
2024-10-07T10:00:51.222081Z 
2024-10-07T10:00:51.222288Z npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2024-10-07T10_00_49_191Z-debug-0.log
2024-10-07T10:00:51.233963Z Error: Exit with error code: 1
2024-10-07T10:00:51.234237Z     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/snapshot/dist/run-build.js)
2024-10-07T10:00:51.234694Z     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:652:26)
2024-10-07T10:00:51.234795Z     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:537:28)
2024-10-07T10:00:51.234902Z     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
2024-10-07T10:00:51.246636Z Failed: build command exited with code: 1
2024-10-07T10:00:52.093279Z Failed: error occurred while running build command

baicd-deploy-website:
2024-10-07T09:59:34.271276Z Cloning repository...
2024-10-07T09:59:36.230574Z From https://github.com/NalaYiyuChen/baicd_deploy
2024-10-07T09:59:36.231063Z  * branch            912db9843a76a916663e4db908e99c1220c78443 -> FETCH_HEAD
2024-10-07T09:59:36.231171Z 
2024-10-07T09:59:36.304856Z HEAD is now at 912db98 website build at  home
2024-10-07T09:59:36.305328Z 
2024-10-07T09:59:36.397073Z 
2024-10-07T09:59:36.397544Z Using v2 root directory strategy
2024-10-07T09:59:36.424286Z Success: Finished cloning repository files
2024-10-07T09:59:38.062519Z Checking for configuration in a wrangler.toml configuration file (BETA)
2024-10-07T09:59:38.063099Z 
2024-10-07T09:59:38.16919Z  No wrangler.toml file found. Continuing.
2024-10-07T09:59:38.328952Z Detected the following tools from environment: npm@9.6.7, nodejs@18.17.1
2024-10-07T09:59:38.329685Z Installing project dependencies: npm clean-install --progress=false
2024-10-07T09:59:41.302324Z npm ERR! code EUSAGE
2024-10-07T09:59:41.305791Z npm ERR! 
2024-10-07T09:59:41.3061Z   npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
2024-10-07T09:59:41.306258Z npm ERR! 
2024-10-07T09:59:41.306384Z npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's @babel/core@7.9.0 does not satisfy @babel/core@7.25.7
2024-10-07T09:59:41.306489Z npm ERR! Missing: @ampproject/remapping@2.3.0 from lock file
2024-10-07T09:59:41.306582Z npm ERR! Missing: convert-source-map@2.0.0 from lock file
2024-10-07T09:59:41.306672Z npm ERR! Missing: @babel/core@7.9.0 from lock file
2024-10-07T09:59:41.306762Z npm ERR! Missing: @babel/core@7.9.0 from lock file
2024-10-07T09:59:41.306852Z npm ERR! Missing: typescript@5.6.2 from lock file
2024-10-07T09:59:41.306975Z npm ERR! Missing: semver@5.7.2 from lock file
2024-10-07T09:59:41.307077Z npm ERR! 
2024-10-07T09:59:41.307189Z npm ERR! Clean install a project
2024-10-07T09:59:41.307302Z npm ERR! 
2024-10-07T09:59:41.30741Z  npm ERR! Usage:
2024-10-07T09:59:41.307517Z npm ERR! npm ci
2024-10-07T09:59:41.307635Z npm ERR! 
2024-10-07T09:59:41.307748Z npm ERR! Options:
2024-10-07T09:59:41.307878Z npm ERR! [--install-strategy <hoisted|nested|shallow|linked>] [--legacy-bundling]
2024-10-07T09:59:41.308048Z npm ERR! [--global-style] [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
2024-10-07T09:59:41.30817Z  npm ERR! [--strict-peer-deps] [--no-package-lock] [--foreground-scripts]
2024-10-07T09:59:41.308297Z npm ERR! [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit] [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
2024-10-07T09:59:41.308451Z npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
2024-10-07T09:59:41.308581Z npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
2024-10-07T09:59:41.308723Z npm ERR! 
2024-10-07T09:59:41.308865Z npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
2024-10-07T09:59:41.309087Z npm ERR! 
2024-10-07T09:59:41.309246Z npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info
2024-10-07T09:59:41.309392Z 
2024-10-07T09:59:41.309553Z npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2024-10-07T09_59_39_112Z-debug-0.log
2024-10-07T09:59:41.322361Z Error: Exit with error code: 1
2024-10-07T09:59:41.322657Z     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/snapshot/dist/run-build.js)
2024-10-07T09:59:41.322927Z     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:652:26)
2024-10-07T09:59:41.323104Z     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:537:28)
2024-10-07T09:59:41.323234Z     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
2024-10-07T09:59:41.336054Z Failed: build command exited with code: 1
2024-10-07T09:59:42.181111Z Failed: error occurred while running build command

Github repo:
https://github.com/NalaYiyuChen/baicd_deploy

Problem here seems to be that package-lock.json is generated on a Mac (look for arm64 in package-lock.json). I could reproduce the error by cloning the repo and run npm ci with Ubuntu 24.04.

Thank you! This is such a late followup, but what would be the solution to this?
